# python urllib2 utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, urllib2

okay, I have: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my python file.

the snippet:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8')]
f =opener.open(url)
doc = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

The server response is: (via f.info())

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

but i get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte[...]: invalid continuation byte
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try decoding the data using 'latin-1' to see what it looks like.  What you're seeing indicates a UTF-8 decode error (see [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) ).

It would be helpful if you posted the result of `list(f.read())[:100]` so we can see the data.

FYI, putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is unrelated to your issue.  *That* encoding refers to the encoding of your python script itself, not the data it is handling :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. list(f.read())[:100] is:`['<', '!', 'D', 'O', 'C', 'T', 'Y', 'P', 'E', ' ', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', ' ', 'P', 'U', 'B', 'L', 'I', 'C', ' ', '"', '-', '/', '/', 'W', '3', 'C', '/', '/', 'D', 'T', 'D', ' ', 'X', 'H', 'T', 'M', 'L', ' ', '1', '.', '0', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'c', 't', '/', '/', 'E', 'N', '"', ' ', '"', 'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'w', 'w', 'w', '.', 'w', '3', '.', 'o', 'r', 'g', '/', 'T', 'R', '/', 'x', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '1', '/', 'D', 'T', 'D', '/', 'x', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '1', '-', 's', 't', 'r']`

Answer (score 1):

That particular error is commonly caused by trying to decode using utf-8 when the string was actually encoded with latin1. See [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) for some more info.

I suspect that despite the header, the server is *not* returning utf8 encoded content.

A solution that might be worth pursuing is to use [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to 'guess' which encoding is used. Despite chardet's awesomeness consider it a last resort however.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Cowie, I tried to use chardet. It's 'guessing' wrong I guess ;). I also tried some random encondings, but I always get shitty text. Surprisingly (for me) I get different outputs for the same character.