# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I launch my app, I get this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2566: invalid continuation byte. I use UTF8 in my HTML file

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

and in my Python file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

I saw some solutions on the Web using the encode() function but I don't want to insert text in the Python file but in HTML file.

Comment: Can you post a traceback? Where is that byte coming from? Are you actually saving the file as UTF-8, or just telling Python that you did?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: It appears the editor you're using does not save as UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @MarkRansom I use IDLE and I configure it to save files in UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @IsmaelToé, does that include your HTML too?

Comment: Ouf! Thank you @MarkRansom I just checked and my HTML files were in ANSI (I use Notepad++). Encode in UTF-8 and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Notepad++ make sure the "encoding" (in the menu) of all your files is set to "UTF-8".

I don't know for other editors but that might be the problem.

Comment: Oh gosh! I just rendered a built-in form in Django and it told me UnicodeEncodeError, I did not understand why since it was a native form and then, thanks to your answer, I checked my N++ encoding :) You saved my day :) Thank you Panda_cat

Answer (score -4):

change to

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-
```

`0xe9` is part of the latin1 charset.

Comment: But that's just propagating the problem, not solving it.