# Mercurial(HG) update with UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: mercurial

When I try to use "hg update", this shows up:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 21: invalid continuation byte
```

This Error occurs in OSX, not in Windows.

Comment: Is there any context to this error? Or is this the complete output? Also, which version of mercurial are you using? The error is likely generated from Python's `decode()` function, where it's seeing an invalid character and trying to interpret it as "utf8". See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5552555/218597

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurred to me and I guessed that's because python use different filename encoding for Windows and other system, you may find details from:

[Mercurial update exception caused by python UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640000/mercurial-update-exception-caused-by-python-unicodedecodeerror/17650434#17650434)