# Mercurial update exception caused by python UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: mercurial

When I pull&update changesets from a remote Hg repo, I got the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/hg", line 38, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 28, in run
    sys.exit((dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])) or 0) & 255)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 65, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(req)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 88, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 741, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 514, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 831, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 802, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 738, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 472, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 144, in wrap
    util.checksignature(origfn), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 472, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgext/mq.py", line 3546, in mqcommand
    return orig(ui, repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 472, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 5916, in update
    ret = hg.update(repo, rev)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 472, in update
    stats = updaterepo(repo, node, False)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 468, in updaterepo
    return mergemod.update(repo, node, False, overwrite, None)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 618, in update
    _checkcollision(p2, None)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 125, in _checkcollision
    fold = util.normcase(fn)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/posix.py", line 198, in normcase
    u = s.decode('utf-8')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 44: invalid continuation byte
```

I found there was a commit that caused the error but it worked fine on my colleague's PC. How can I just skip that changeset or there is some other way to fix my local repo?

Comment: What system you are using?  What system is your colleague using?  Are the mercurial versions different?  Could you isolate the problem by creating a minimal repo and provide instructions to reproduce the error?

Comment: What I am using is Mac OS, Mercurial 2.4 and Python 2.7.2, and my colleague's is Windows, Mercurial 1.5 and Python2.6.4.
After I pulled all the changesets, I found `hg update -r 1960` worked fine, but `hg update -r 1961` prompted the UnicodeDecodeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I upgraded Mercurial to 2.6, the problem was solved. I guess the reason was that python use different encoding for the filename on Windows and other systems:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3UnicodeDecodeError

And Mercurial 2.6 added some code to handle the possible DecodeError:

```
try:
        path.decode('ascii') # throw exception for non-ASCII character
        return path.lower()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
    try:
        u = path.decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # OS X percent-encodes any bytes that aren't valid utf-8
        s = ''
        g = ''
        l = 0
        for c in path:
            o = ord(c)
            if l and o < 128 or o >= 192:
                # we want a continuation byte, but didn't get one
                s += ''.join(["%%%02X" % ord(x) for x in g])
                g = ''
                l = 0
            if l == 0 and o < 128:
                # ascii
                s += c
            elif l == 0 and 194 <= o < 245:
                # valid leading bytes
                if o < 224:
                    l = 1
                elif o < 240:
                    l = 2
                else:
                    l = 3
                g = c
            elif l > 0 and 128 <= o < 192:
                # valid continuations
                g += c
                l -= 1
                if not l:
                    s += g
                    g = ''
            else:
                # invalid
                s += "%%%02X" % o

        # any remaining partial characters
        s += ''.join(["%%%02X" % ord(x) for x in g])
        u = s.decode('utf-8')`
```

in posix.py