# Python pandas to_excel 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, excel, utf-8, pandas

I'm trying to do some data work in Python pandas and having trouble writing out my results.
I read my data in as a CSV file and been exporting each script as it's own CSV file which works fine. Lately though I've tried exporting everything in 1 Excel file with worksheets and a few of the sheets give me an error

"'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte"

I have no idea how to even start finding any characters that could be causing problems exporting to Excel. Not sure why it exports to CSV just fine though :(

relevant lines

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
data = pd.read_csv(input)
writer = ExcelWriter(output) #output is just the filename
fundraisers.to_excel(writer, "fundraisers")
locations.to_excel(writer, "locations") #error
locations.to_csv(outputcsv) #works
writer.save()
```

printing head of offending dataframe

```
Event ID    Constituent ID  Email Address   First Name  \   Last Name
f       1       A       A       1
F       4       L       R       C
M       1       1       A       D
F       4       A       A       G
M       2       0       R       G
M       3       O       O       H
M       2       T       E       H
M       2       A       A       H
M       2       M       M       K
F       3       J       E       K
Location ID raised  raised con  raised email
a   0   0   0
a   8   0   0
o   0   0   0
o   0   0   0
o   0   0   0
t   5   0   0
o   1   0   0
o   6   a   0
o   6   0   0
d   0   0   0
```

looking at the excel sheet I do actually get a partial print out. Anything in the first name column and beyond are blank, but event, constituent and email all print.

edit: Trying to read the csv in as utf8 fails, but reading it in as latin1 works. Is there a way to specify the to_excel encoding? Or decode and encode my dataframe to utf8?

Comment: Can you post some of your possibly offending unicode characters? Generating random Hebrew characters and then writing them works okay for me.

Comment: I have no idea how to find which character it finds offensive.

Comment: One reason that CSV is different is because the Excel exporting is not done by `pandas` it is done by third-party libraries (`xlwt` and/or `openpyxl`).

Comment: Since the error message says "... in position 1", you can start by looking at every *second* character of every one of your unicode columns. Just show a few of them.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: I've had problems in the past where I was reading CSV files into Pandas that were utf8 encoded without specifying the encoding.  e.g. try pd.read_csv(input, encoding='utf-8') and similar on write.  Or maybe you have 'latin-1' input data - seems to pop up in google search for your error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Managed to solve this.

I made a function that goes through my columns that have strings and managed to decode/encode them into utf8 and it now works.

```
def changeencode(data, cols):
    for col in cols:
        data[col] = data[col].str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks! This function was quite useful. It would be helpful for Pandas to have this type of capability built in, instead of just throwing a less than insightful error (or at least identifying the first row and column in which it encountered the problem).

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the problem was that I was initially *reading* the CSV file with the wrong encoding (`ASCII` instead of `cp1252`). Therefore, when pandas tried to write it to an Excel file, it found some characters it couldn't decode.

I solved it by specifying the correct encoding when reading the CSV file.

```
data = pd.read_csv(fname, encoding='cp1252')
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a way to force utf8 encoding by passing a parameter to ExcelWriter:

```
 ew = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',options={'encoding':'utf-8'})
 sampleList = ['Miño', '1', '2', 'señora']
 dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(sampleList)
 dataframe.to_excel(ew)
 ew.save()
```

Comment: In `.to_csv` also takes an optional `encoding` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to load your dataframe in utf-8. Then it ExcelWriter will save it no problem.

```
data = pd.read_csv(path,encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

don't know when it's going to be released but you can try with my github repository:

https://github.com/jtornero/pandas

You can clone it and build pandas from source; the issue is almost solved and it works like

```
sampleList = ['Miño', '1', '2', 'señora']
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(sampleList)
ew = pandas.ExcelWriter('./test.xls', encoding='utf-8')
dataframe.to_excel(ew)
ew.save()
```

Cheers

Jorge Tornero

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what was said by @Zenadix, reading the csvs in as UTF-8 allowed the ExcelWriter to write without an error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('path', encoding='utf-8')

...

with pd.ExcelWriter('new_path') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Foo')
```