# Can't export pandas dataframe to excel / encoding

Tags: python, pandas, xlwt

I'm unable to export one of my dataframes due to some encoding difficulty.

```
sjM.dtypes

Customer Name              object
Total Sales               float64
Sales Rank                float64
Visit_Frequency           float64
Last_Sale          datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

csv export works fine

```
path = 'c:\\test'
sjM.to_csv(path + '.csv')   # Works
```

but the excel export fails

```
sjM.to_excel(path + '.xls')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testing.py", line 338, in <module>
    sjM.to_excel(path + '.xls')
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1197, in to_excel
    excel_writer.save()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 595, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 637, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 599, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 76, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 91, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know that the problem is coming from the 'Customer Name' column, as after deletion the export to excel works fine.

I've tried following advice from that question ([Python pandas to_excel 'utf8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645401/python-pandas-to-excel-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte)), using a function to decode and re-encode the offending column

```
def changeencode(data):
    cols = data.columns
    for col in cols:
        if data[col].dtype == 'O':
            data[col] = data[col].str.decode('latin-1').str.encode('utf-8')
    return data

sJM = changeencode(sjM)

sjM['Customer Name'].str.decode('utf-8')

L2-00864                         SETIA 2
K1-00279                     BERKAT JAYA
L2-00664                        TK. ANTO
BR00035                   BRASIL JAYA,TK
RA00011               CV. RAHAYU SENTOSA
```

so the conversion to unicode appears to be successful

```
sjM.to_excel(path + '.xls')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1197, in to_excel
    excel_writer.save()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 595, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 637, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 599, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 76, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 91, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

1. Why does it fails, even though the conversion to unicode appears to be successful ?
2. How can i work around this issue to export that dataframe to excel ?

@Jeff

Thanks for showing me the right direction

steps used :

install xlsxwriter (not bundled with pandas)

```
sjM.to_excel(path + '.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: I was getting this same problem and I fixed it using [this solution from @eumiro][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13682381/2797460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use pandas >= 0.13, and the `xlsxwriter` engine for excel, which supports native unicode writing. `xlwt`, the default engine will support passing an encoding option will be available in 0.14.

see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-writer-engines) for the engine docs.

Comment: Had the same problem. Txs for the feedback knightofni and @Jeff