# Pandas: save to excel encoding issue

Tags: python, excel, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I have a similar problem to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681615/cant-export-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-encoding) but none of the suggested methods work for me.

I have a medium size `utf-8` .csv file with a lot of non-ascii characters.
I am splitting the file by a particular value from one of the columns, and then I'd like to save each of the obtained dataframes as an .xlsx file with the characters preserved.

This doesn't work, as I am getting an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is what I tried:

1. Using `xlsxwriter` engine explicitly. This doesn't seem to change anything.
2. Defining a function (below) to change encoding and throw away bad characters. This also doesn't change anything.

   ```
   def changeencode(data):
   cols = data.columns
   for col in cols:
   if data[col].dtype == 'O':
       data[col] = data[col].str.decode('utf-8').str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
   return data
   ```
3. Changing by hand all the offensive chars to some others. Still no effect (the quoted error was obtained after this change).
4. Encoding the file as `utf-16` (which, I believe, is the correct encoding since I want to be able to manipulate the file from within the excel afterwards) doesn't help either.

I believe that the problem is in the file itself (because of 2 and 3) but I have no idea how to get around it. I'd appreciate any help. The beginning of the file is pasted below.

```
"Submitted","your-name","youremail","phone","miasto","cityCF","innemiasto","languagesCF","morelanguages","wiek","partnerCF","messageCF","acceptance-795","Submitted Login","Submitted From","2015-12-25 14:07:58 +00:00","Zózia kryś","test@tes.pl","4444444","Wrocław","","testujemy polskie znaki","Polski","testujemy polskie znaki","44","test","test","1","Justyna","99.111.155.132",
```

**EDIT**

Some code (one of the versions, without the splitting part):

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_csv('path-to-file.csv')

with pd.ExcelWriter ('test.xlsx') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet1',engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: Have you already tried `df.to_excel(path, encoding='utf8')`?

Comment: @Stefan I have, thanks for asking. To be sure, I tried this one more time - just now. Still nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Supposedly this was a bug in the version of `pandas` which I was using back then. 
Right now, in `pandas` ver. 0.19.2, the code below saves the csv from the question without any trouble (and with correct encoding).
NB: `openpyxl` module have to be installed on your system.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/test.csv')
df.to_excel('Desktop/test.xlsx', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: @greghor hmm, weird. I installed the same version just now, and it works for me. Do you have `openpyxl` installed?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I do have openpyxl 2-5-0 installed. After strugling for while, I noticed that if I specify the encoding when loading the data `df=pd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding="utf-8")`, then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding the columns with non-ascii characters as

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: unicode(x))
```

and then save the file to xlsx format with encoding 'utf8'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately this doesn't work. The same error is returned but now it is triggered by the `.apply` line.

Comment: Can you attach snippet of the csv file here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. A part of the file which should be enough to trigger the error is posted in my question. Do you want something more?

Answer (score 0):

What if you save the csv files from pandas and then use win32com to convert to Excel. It would look something like this...

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = 0

for x in range(10): 
    f = path + str(x)
    # not showing the pandas dataframe creation
    df.to_csv(f+'.csv')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f+'.csv')
    wb.SaveAs(f+'.xlsx', 51) #xlOpenXMLWorkbook=51
```