# how to save string in 'utf-8' format in a .xlsx using pandas to_exel (to_csv is able to save it as .csv)

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, encoding, utf-8

since I am able to save string using to_csv using 'utf-8' encoding, I am expecting to do be able to do the same using to_excel. This is not an issue on my side with encoding. None of the previous thread I saw, discuss this issue.

I am using python 2.7.12 on Windows 7(Anaconda) and pandas 0.18.1

I have 2 questions related to saving a panda dataframe containing special character (encoding as 'utf-8') as a .csv or .xlsx file.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['1', 'as', '?%','ä']})
```

I can save the dataframe as a .cvs file without any issue:

```
df.to_csv('test_csv.csv',sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

and it works. When importng the data I need to choose 'utf-8' in Excel and everything is fine.

Now if I try to save the same dataframe as an .xlsx then it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

```
 # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',   options={'encoding':'utf-8'})

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',encoding='utf-8')
writer.save()
```

and I got the following error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   7: ordinal not in range(128)

I am not 100% sure to use the correct option to set the encoding:

```
options={'encoding':'utf-8'}
```

and

```
encoding='utf-8'
```

since it is not clear to me how to proceed from the documentation.

Any idea how to have this working ?

Bonus question related to df.to_csv. Is there a way to use some special character as separator ? Some reason, the code I am migrated from R to python is using sep='¤'.  tried to encode this special character in all possible way but is always failed. Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Fabien

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: save to excel encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485982/pandas-save-to-excel-encoding-issue)

Comment: favorite
 

This question may already have an answer here:

    Pandas: save to excel encoding issue 2 answers

since I am able to save the string using to_csv using 'utf-8' encoding, I am expecting to do be able to do the same using to_excel. This is not an issue on my side with encoding. None of the previous thread I saw, discuss this issue. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `xlsxwriter` as the Excel writing engine then the `encoding='utf-8'` is ignored because the XlsxWriter module doesn't use it.

XlsxWriter requires that the string data is encoded as `utf8`. After that it handles the strings automatically.

So you will need to ensure that the string data you are writing is encoded as `utf8` via Pandas: either when you read it or after the data is in the data frame.

Comment: Thanks  @jmcnamara, this explain my issue. By fixing the encoding in the dataframe fix my issue.