# Pandas dataframe to excel gives "file is not UTF-8 encoded"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, utf-8

I'm working on lists that I want to export into an Excel file.

I found a lot of people advising to use pandas.dataframe so that's what I did. I could create the dataframe but when I try to export it to Excel, the file is empty, there is just the following message:

> " Error! [file_pathway] is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled. See console for more details".

I didn't see any more info on the console, and every example I found on the Internet leads to the same error message.

The different lists I'm using contain different types of data. So I try to convert every element I could into a UTF-8 encoded element. I couldn't do it for the "float" list nor for the "NoType" list.

After that, here is what I wrote :

```
d = {'Dataset_name': dataset_names, 'Parameter_name': para_names, 'Parameter_amount': para_amounts, 'Parameter_unit': para_units, 'Parameter_variable': para_variables, 'Parameter_formula': para_formulas}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('Ocelot_Export.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, encoding='utf8', index=False)
writer.save()
```

The dataframe is correct, as I can print it in Jupyter Notebook. The only problem is the exportation. Please let me know if you have any idea about what's wrong.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Is it maybe the (absolute) path that contains non-ASCII characters, rather than the content?

Comment: Stephen Rauch, I don't understand what you mean. What are the input, expected test data and editor you're talking about?
Ienz, I'm working in a Jupyter notebook and the Excel file that is created is sent to the folder inside Jupyter Notebook. Do you think this is a problem?

Answer (score 15):

The cause of this problem is likely just that jupyter is unable to display `.xlsx` files. Try downloading the file from jupyter (checkbox next to the file name -> "Download" button near the page header) onto your local machine and open it using excel.

**2020 Update**: If you're using Jupyter Lab, [jupyterlab-spreadsheet](https://github.com/quigleyj97/jupyterlab-spreadsheet) is a great way to view excel files without leaving your browser.

Comment: Yup, that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for `df.to_excel` function shows that you do not have a parameter to specify encoding. So you can try using the `df.to_csv` function instead and specify the utf8 encoding like below:

```
dataframe.to_csv(csv_buffer, encoding = 'utf8', index = False)
```

Also, I see that you can upgrade your pandas version and it will allow you to specify the encoding parameter as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485982/pandas-save-to-excel-encoding-issue).

Comment: This will write a CSV file, not a proper Excel file. For many scenarios, this is _way_ better; but it's not what the OP asked.