# trouble with utf-8 with julia and jupyterlab

Tags: dataframe, utf-8, julia, xlsx, jupyter-lab

I'm reading the csv file at https://github.com/VinitaSilaparasetty/julia-beginners/blob/master/data/nba/nba19-20.csv

I get a DataFrame and I save it as XLSX. When I try to read it in jupyterlab I get the error `the file is not UTF-8 encoded` and therefore the file is not read.

This is my code:

```
using HTTP, XLSX, CSV, DataFrames
df = CSV.read(HTTP.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VinitaSilaparasetty/julia-beginners/master/data/nba/nba19-20.csv").body)
# first(df,5) # first shows the top five rows ok
XLSX.writetable("data/nba/nba19-20.XLSX", collect(eachcol(df)), names(df), overwrite = true)
```

The file is saved in my data folder.  When I try to open it with jupyterlab, I get a pop up with the `file is not UTF-8 encoded` and the file is not opened.
When I try to open the file in Ubuntu (with LibreOffice) I do not see anything suspicious.

As I'm new to Julia I'm struggling to understand where the problem lies or how to fix it.

I tried to see if I could encode the dataframe in UTF-8 (after saving the file to disk) with

```
data = DataFrame(CSV.File(open(read,"data/nba/nba19-20.csv", enc"utf-8")))
```

But I did not see any change. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the [jupyterlab-spreadsheet](https://github.com/quigleyj97/jupyterlab-spreadsheet) plugin installed? JupyterLab by default doesn't support opening xlsx files (it isn't mentioned in [the file formats list here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/file_formats.html) for example).

See also [this similar question involving Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967861/pandas-dataframe-to-excel-gives-file-is-not-utf-8-encoded) (which says pretty much the same thing).