# to_excel 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save a pandas dataframe as an excel sheet. The dataframe as names with Ö, Ä, Å, Ø, Æ due to which i get the error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using the following code of lines:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/filepath/filename.xls')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

I tried several solutions as specified by the following but no success:

1. [Python pandas to_excel 'utf8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645401/python-pandas-to-excel-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte)
2. [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)
3. [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Example code:

I have the following code as an example dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['Äse', 'SÖA'], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now if try to save it using the following lines of code, I get the ascii, unicode error.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/filepath/filename.xls')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

I tried adding the "encoding='utf8'" parameter to to_excel as well as removing the first three lines but it did not work.

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Can anybody help in this matter?

Comment: Usually adding encoding to your `to_excel` will do the trick: `result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False,encoding='utf8')`

Comment: did you try setting utf-8 as encoding parameter in to_excel

Comment: Yes, I tried with encoding='utf8' in to_excel but no success. Following are the first lines of the error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-315-13407f88c1d8> in <module>()
       

        result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False,encoding='utf8')

----> writer.save()

Comment: If you can put a working code, we can help you more because we can't recreate your problem.

Comment: `You should not use non-Unicode Python version.`

Comment: @O.Suleiman I have now edited my question and added an example code.

Comment: I tried your example code without the `sys` lines and without adding any encoding to `to_excel` and it worked, my environment: Python 3.6.2 / Pandas 0.20.3. Output: https://imgur.com/a/4f2SC

Comment: @O.Suleiman Strange it did not work for me. But the solution by Roee Shenberg worked in my case.

Comment: According to pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html 

encoding: string, default None
encoding of the resulting excel file. Only necessary for xlwt, other writers support unicode natively.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are your Python and Pandas versions?

Comment: @O.Suleiman I am using Python 2.7 and pandas 0.22.0 versions. I have saved a dozen of files without any encoding issues even though those files had special characters as now i have in the current file, but this is the first time i got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the `encoding` parameter to the ExcelWriter constructor, not in the `to_excel()` call:

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/path/to/file.xls', encoding='utf-8')
>>> df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
>>> writer.save()
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Earlier, I used encoding='utf8' but it did not work, now I changed to encoding='utf-8' and adding this '-' helped I guess.

Comment: The difference is encoding on the constructor, not on the `to_excel()` call