# docx file downloaded from Django is corrupt

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, python-requests

Im trying to take user input from a form and then using that data to create a document using python docx module. But the downloaded file is not opening in MS word. It says the file is corrupt. Can someone help me with this?

```
def resume_form(request):
form = forms.resume()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.resume(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        document = Document()
        document.add_heading(str(form.cleaned_data['full_name']),0)
        document.add_heading('Summary', 1)
        document.add_paragraph(str(form.cleaned_data['summary']))

        f = io.BytesIO()
        document.save(f)
        length = f.tell()
        f.seek(0)
        response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.docx'
        response['Content-Length'] = length
        #document.save(response)
        return response

return render(request, 'sample_app/index.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: you are corrupting the file in this line check the correct extension in this line for document .  response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')

Comment: I tried for .doc from this website:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/
Its still corrupt

Comment: check if this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400089/downloadable-docx-file-in-django

Comment: `if form.is_valid():
            document = Document()
            document.add_heading(str(form.cleaned_data['full_name']),0)
            document.add_heading('Summary', 1)
            document.add_paragraph(str(form.cleaned_data['summary']))
            response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/vnd.ms-word')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.docx'
            document.save(response)
            return response`

Comment: I tried changing the extension and a few other changes. But its still not working. 
I opened the file in notepad,
It looks something like this:


‰–ÄaLÎ^ÓØ« ƒrálv®ZOâèÞ[1Û¶

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the answer already in your code: you can (and should) write your document directly to the response, rather than use an intermediary `BytesIO`.

```
...
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "download.docx"'
document.save(response)
return response
```

Comment: Thank you :)  I was trying to solve the warning sign for 'corrupt file' that I forgot to actually open(force) the word file. Can you tell me why the prompt/sign appears?

Comment: You mean the prompt to download the file? I think that is a a Content-Disposition/attachment thing, but I'm new to this, so not sure if there's a way to disable it (particularly for a word document).

Answer (score 1):

You must read from `io` in the response with `getvalue()`, since you're writing document to `io`.

```
response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
```

Or you can write directly to response as @paleolimbot pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to change that part.