# Downloading files from a website on django

Tags: python, django

I have a website on a debian server. I fill out the template in docx format and save it. How do I download it to the user's devices?

```
 post_data = json.loads(request.body)
    date = post_data.get('date', False)
    price = post_data.get('price', False)
    pricesum = post_data.get('pricesum', False)
    startdate = post_data.get('startdate', False)
    enddate = post_data.get('enddate', False)


    doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

    dates = date
    prices = price

    tbl_contents = [{'expirationdate': expirationdate, 'price': price}
                    for expirationdate, price in zip(dates, prices)]

    context = {
        'tbl_contents': tbl_contents,
        'finalprice': sum(prices),
        'startdate': startdate,
        'enddate': enddate
    }

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("static.docx")
```

Comment: Just take that file URL saved in the cloud and just link it to an HTML page that's it

Comment: Can you offer me some ready-made example? I don't quite understand how this can be implemented

Comment: Django is used for Backend operations so from there u cant provide an option for downloading a file but from the backend get the File URL from the cloud then render it respective template

Comment: It will be better if you share all the respective codes through Github or any collaboration platform

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it with this method.
My answer is inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400089/downloadable-docx-file-in-django)
I hope it helps.

```
def fun(request):
    ...
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.docx'
    doc.save(response)
    return response
```