# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

I want to convert a byte variable to string. Of course, there are  previous questions related to mine. However, trying to hash in md5() the content of a file this way:

```
import hashlib
with open("C:\\boot.ini","r") as f:
    r=f.read()
a=hashlib.md5()
a.update(r.encode('utf8'))
bytes_data=a.digest()
print(bytes_data)
r=type(bytes_data)
print(r) # <-- Just to be sure, it is in bytes 
myString=bytes_data.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

I understand the reason of my problem thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte), however I am dealing with different files to calculate their hash, so I have no control on the bytes, so how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`hash.digest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) return value is **not** a UTF-8-encoded string. Don't try to decode it; it is a sequence of bytes in the range 0-255 and these bytes do **not** represent text.

Not all `bytes` contents encode text; this is one such value.

Use [`hash.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) if you want something printable instead. This method returns the bytes expressed as hexadecimal numbers instead (two hex characters per digest byte). This is the commonly used form when sharing a MD5 digest with others.