# unicode error in python: can't decode byte

Tags: python

I am trying to dump a json content like:

```
foo = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

But I am seeing the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 33: invalid continuation byte
```

How should I en/decode it properly ?

Comment: I've given you a generic answer, because you neglected to give us sample `data` that reproduces your problem. Please provide us with a [mcve] if you want to get specific help.

Comment: Check this answer for a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains `str` objects that contain non-UTF-8 bytes. All text in JSON is *Unicode*, so `str` values are decoded to Unicode assuming UTF-8.

If that does not apply to all text in your `data`, you either need to decode it to Unicode before dumping to JSON, or you need to tell the `dumps()` function what codec to decode bytestrings with:

```
foo = simplejson.dumps(data, encoding='<codec for bytestrings in data>')
```