# How to decode character to utf-8 at specific position

Tags: centos, python, character-encoding

I have a python script, in which there is a dictionary. For some reason, I need to convert dictionary to json.
But, whenever script executed, It gives below error

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 604: invalid continuation byte**

for line **json.dumps(data_dict)**.

From [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte), I understand that non utf character should be decoded. But how to do it in a script? How we can get character at that positon from dictionary and decode it.

On interpreter, it works. Below is interpreter snippet.

>>'ren�'.decode('utf-8')

>>u'ren\ufffd'

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to decode an invalid UTF-8 codepoint. Non-UTF-8 characters cannot be decoded. Try passing `'ignore`' to `.decode` if you absolutely must handle invalid codepoints, or try the [chardet library](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) to detect the actual encoding (`.decode` will encode into Unicode).