# Extract rows based on the particular value from a particular column and export it to new csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**CSV file as stack.csv**

```
PROBLEM_CODE;OWNER_EMAIL;CALENDAR_YEAR;CALENDAR_QUARTER
CONFIG_ASSISTANCE;dalangle@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
ERROR_MESSAGES;aganju@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
PASSWORD_RECOV;dalangle@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
ERROR_MESSAGES;biyma@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
ERROR_MESSAGES;derrlee@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
SOFTWARE_FAILURE;dalangle@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
ERROR_MESSAGES;maariano@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
SOFTWARE_FAILURE;dalangle@gmail.com;2014;2014Q3
```

---

**My Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd 
import csv
data = pd.read_csv('stack.csv', sep='delimiter')
min_indices = (data['OWNER_EMAIL'] == dalangle@gmail.com)
data = data[min_indices]
data.to_csv('isabevdata.csv')
```

---

**Error:**

> KeyError: 'OWNER_EMAIL'

---

I need help with this code using pandas. I want to remove some columns later on from the result: `isabevdata.csv` --> using petl module and then send the table to front end for display

Comment: it should be: `pd.read_csv('stack.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: I am still getting error as :: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 14: invalid continuation byte" .

Comment: The actual csv file on which i am working is having 28k rows and 30 columns. When I am using small csv file as one mentioned above i get no error . but when I am trying to work with big amount of data, i get this error

Comment: you need to wrap `dalangle@gmail.com` in quotes `'dalangle@gmail.com'` as well as `sep=';'`

Comment: Thanks MaxU and piRSquared, it works well with test data , but like I said with a big chunk of data , i get below error ::

Comment: File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1402, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas\parser.c:19247)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 14: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @deepmanharshwardhan can you show us what line 1402 looks like?

Comment: try adding `encoding='utf-8'` to the `read_csv` call

Comment: in the above shared line , ";;" , I have verified that they are blank cells and at the end ";;" is same for every row.

Comment: @PaulH Tried  encoding= 'utf-8' , no luck

Comment: There are characters that are not unicode encoded. Either get the unicode encoded csv from the source and work on it or read the file as a normal binary file do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5552623/2650427 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5552616/2650427 and then feed that data to pandas. Before going that way you can also try ```encoding="lain-1"```