# Vertica Python reading results throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, encode

I am just doing a pull down of a database table and trying to read it into python like so:

`with query(full_query_string) as cur:
    arr = cur.fetchall()`

This produces the following error from the `fetchall()`:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte`

If I `select *` I get this error whereas if I limit to a small number of rows, I don't get this error. I tried paying around with a few encodings following this SO post [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) but none of them are doing the trick. In a large db table where I don't know how the encoding could have gone wrong, what's the most efficient way to deal with this? Also, no specific row is a must-have, but I'd rather get all the rows other than whichever ones have this encoding problem.

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is not latin-1? How did you try dealing with the encoding?

Answer (score 5):

Hey I know this is a super-late answer but in trying to debug a similar issue I found this fix from the vertica-python README:

> While Vertica expects varchars stored to be UTF-8 encoded, sometimes
>   invalid strings get into the database. You can specify how to handle
>   reading these characters using the unicode_error connection option.
>   This uses the same values as the unicode type
>   (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode)

Try changing the 'unicode_error' key in your connection params from `strict` to either `replace` or `ignore`:

```
cur = vertica_python.Connection({..., 'unicode_error': 'strict'}).cursor() 
cur.execute(r"SELECT E'\xC2'") cur.fetchone()
# caught 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: unexpected end of data

cur = vertica_python.Connection({..., 'unicode_error': 'replace'}).cursor() 
cur.execute(r"SELECT E'\xC2'") cur.fetchone()
# �

cur = vertica_python.Connection({..., 'unicode_error': 'ignore'}).cursor() 
cur.execute(r"SELECT E'\xC2'") cur.fetchone()
#
```