# Getting error during decoding

Tags: python-3.x, decode

I am using the below code for decoding:-

```
for tweet in posfile:
        tweet = tweet.decode('utf-8')
        tweet = clean(tweet)
        train_tweets.append(tweet)
        count = count + 1
```

While using the above code. I am getting the below error.
[image]

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: probably would need to inspect the contents of the "tweet", or have more information on what encoding was used

Comment: may also be a duplicate of, or be a helpful reference here: [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)