# python 3.6 pandas - transfer csv data to excel in loop

Tags: python, excel, csv

This is the code that I wrote. I don't understand why I get an error message.

```
import CSV

import openpyxl

import xlsxwriter

from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter

import pandas


def create_excell_from_csv():

arr = ['users', 'account']

dest_filename = r'transformed.xlsx'

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(dest_filename)

with ExcelWriter(dest_filename) as ew:

        for arr1 in arr:

            wb.add_worksheet('sh_' + arr1)

            pandas.read_csv(arr1 + '.csv').to_excel(ew, index=FALSE, sheet_name='sh_sh_users' , encoding='utf-8' )

        wb.add_worksheet('Sheet').hide()


create_excell_from_csv()
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: all this: "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" C:/Users/autosrv/Desktop/python_testing/A1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/autosrv/Desktop/python_testing/A1.py", line 17, in <module>
    create_excell_from_csv()

Comment: and this:   File "C:/Users/autosrv/Desktop/python_testing/A1.py", line 14, in create_excell_from_csv
    pandas.read_csv(arr1 + '.csv').to_excel(ew, index=FALSE, sheet_name='sh_sh_users' , encoding='utf-8' )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 449, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

Comment: and this:   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1049, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

Comment: and this:   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 790, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: now it create the excel with the sheets, but theres no data inside of them