# Saving Converted Unicode from Serial Port in Python

Tags: python, unicode, arduino, serial-port

I am struggling to read in data from an Arduino and save this data as a csv file I could meddle with in Python later. Right now my code reads.

`import serial
    serial_port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    baud_rate = 9600
    file_path = "output.csv"
    ser  = serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate)
    done = False
    data = []
    while done == False:
        raw_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(raw_bytes.decode("utf-8"))
        data.append(decoded_bytes)
        if (len(data) > 10) :
            done = True
    import numpy as np
    np.savetxt(file_path, data, delimiter = ',', fmt='%s')`

but I'm running into the error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

I want to decode into UTF-8 don't I? What is going wrong? I have checked the Serial Monitor on the Arduino IDE and I am getting correct outputs there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this answer helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: Which coding do you use on the Arduino side? Eventually the same you used for coding your sketch. That's probably the same SerialMonitor uses. My Windows still prefers ANSI (CP-1252  8 bit) . However F0 is a strange ð there.

Comment: @datafiddler how do I check this? I'm running a chipkit uC32 with the Arduino IDE on an Ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

If there's no other way to find out which coding your Arduino IDE uses, you can check/guess the coding on the Arduino side by returning the codes for characters in question via SerialMonitor

```
 void loop () {
    int c = Serial.read();
    if ( c == -1 ) return;  // nothing available
    Serial.println (c, HEX);  // return the character code in hex notation
 }
```

However the characters you use to convert text into a float number should be plain ASCII, so your

> float(raw_bytes.decode("utf-8"))

would probably fail anyway.