# Error in reading csv <UnicodeDecodeError>

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

getting these kind of errors while importing the file

```
import pandas
data1 = pandas.read_csv("zomato.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1149, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1279, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1295, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1518, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: You have some encoding issue with your `csv` hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass an `encoding` option when you read a CSV file

```
data1 = pandas.read_csv('zomato.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Refer here for other encoding options [Encoding alretnatives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)