# Enable to decode/encode correctly   from bytes in python 3.7.3

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, cesu-8

I'm struggling with this:

`b'"\xc2\xb7\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x96\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xb1\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x9d\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xbe\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xaf \xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xa9\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xa4\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x93\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xa9\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x9a\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\xa7\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x91"@en'`

which comes from a binary format coming from the HDT compressed version (https://github.com/rdfhdt/hdt-cpp) of (dbpedia 3.5.1 (http://dbpedia.org/page/Shavian_alphabet)) and is well decoded in utf8 by this website (https://mothereff.in/utf-8)

And the meaning is: "· "@en

But in python 3.7.3 I encountered the well-known error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3: invalid continuation byte` when trying to `mystring.decode('utf8')`

If I try to do the contrary:  `'"· "@en'.encode('utf8)`I get the following representation: `b'"\xf0\x90\x91\x96\xf0\x90\x91\xb1\xf0\x90\x91\x9d\xf0\x90\x91\xbe\xf0\x90\x91\xaf \xf0\x90\x91\xa8\xf0\x90\x91\xa4\xf0\x90\x91\x93\xf0\x90\x91\xa9\xf0\x90\x91\x9a\xf0\x90\x91\xa7\xf0\x90\x91\x91"@en'` which is not the exact same string, but is then decoded `repr.decode('utf8')` correctly into the same thing....

**Can someone help me to understand why decoding the first bytes string is not working? 
I know the first bytes string is not a valid UTF-8 string due to the error. 
But then, why is it well decoded by the website I linked and cant be done by python?
Thank you in advance!**

---

**FINAL EDIT**
After having accepted the answer I did a few extra researches on this and found this string was encoded using the CESU-8 codec. Which is clearly deprecated today. But some are still using it... So, I found a package which write a variants of the utf-8 codec which can decode this string. I think it will help a lot of people with the same problem as me.
Python library: https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy
The added codec is 'utf-8-variants'. I hope this will help people in the same needs than me.

Comment: Are you asking `why does it work on that website?` or are you asking `how do I convert this bytestring to 'xyz...'?`

Comment: Both, I think,. How to convert this bytesstring and how does it work on the website?

Comment: Related: [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: @wwii In this case, it is not really an invalid continuation byte, but a problem on the next level, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that Python does not want to accept some sequence of bytes as valid UTF-8, whereas some website (https://mothereff.in/utf-8) accepts it. One of them must be wrong, right? Let's see.

The first two bytes (`b'\xc2\xb7'`) are accepted by Python. The first thing which Python does not like is this: `\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x96`, which is interpreted on that website as .

Let's look at `\xed\xa0\x81\xed\xb1\x96` in binary format:

```
11101101
10100000
10000001
11101101
10110001
10010110
```

[RFC3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) says that UTF-8 is interpreted as:

> ```
>    Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
>       (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
>    --------------------+---------------------------------------------
>    0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
>    0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
>    0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
>    0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
> ```

Therefore, there are two three-byte characters:

1110**1101** 10**100000** 10**000001** ⇒ 1101100000000001, or D801

1110**1101** 10**110001** 10**010110** ⇒ 1101110001010110, or DC56

Character `D801` is one of the [high surrogates](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/high-surrogates/) and `DC56` is one of the [low surrogates](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/low-surrogates/).

You can see [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/low-surrogates/) how to combine the surrogates:

> A surrogate pair denotes the code point 0x10000 + (H − 0xD800) × 0x400
>
> - (L − 0xDC00) where H and L are the numeric values of the high and low surrogates respectively.

If you combine them, you'll get:

0x10000 + (0xD801 - 0xD800) * 0x400 + (0xDC56 - 0xDC00) = 0x10456, which is

However, the high and low surrogates were designed for UTF-16 representation of characters which do not fit into 16 bits, and this is [what unicode.org says](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4) about using such surrogate pairs in UTF-8:

> **Q: How do I convert a UTF-16 surrogate pair such as `<D800 DC00>` to UTF-8? As one 4-byte sequence or as two separate 3-byte sequences?**
>
> A: The definition of UTF-8 requires that supplementary characters
> (those using surrogate pairs in UTF-16) be encoded with a single
> 4-byte sequence. However, there is a widespread practice of generating
> pairs of 3-byte sequences in older software, especially software which
> pre-dates the introduction of UTF-16 or that is interoperating with
> UTF-16 environments under particular constraints. Such an encoding is
> not conformant to UTF-8 as defined. See [UTR #26: Compatability Encoding Scheme for UTF-16: 8-bit (CESU)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr26/) for a formal description of
> such a non-UTF-8 data format. When using CESU-8, great care must be
> taken that data is not accidentally treated as if it was UTF-8, due to
> the similarity of the formats. [[AF]](https://unicode.org/faq/attribution.html#AF)

The key point here is *"Such an encoding is not conformant to UTF-8 as defined"*. So, your input is in fact an invalid UTF-8 sequence, and Python rejected it as such.

To answer the question:

- https://mothereff.in/utf-8 is ignoring the unicode.org's instruction
  to treat this as invalid.
- Python is treating this as invalid.
- If you want to decode it, even though it is invalid, you can write a
  function which does what I did manually.

Comment: Btw, do you have any idea of a library doing this (to not reinvent the wheel)?
If not I'll create my own converter based on your indications.

Comment: @Folkvir I'm afraid I don't know of such a library. It might exists. It's up to you to decide whether to spend time looking for it or reinventing the wheel ;)