# Why do I have "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte " problem and how do I solve it?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am trying to run the simple code, to play the wav sound with playsound (I found this way of sound playing on some website):

```
from playsound import playsound 

playsound("Piano.wav")
```

and when I run it, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/ьгышсф.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound("Piano.wav")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Same for mp3 files. And I am using Python 3.8

Comment: try the same code in Python 2

Comment: Looks like the error message that's created by the OS contains some characters that aren't in utf-8. As a quick fix, try changing playsound.py line 30 from `'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())` to `'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode(errors="ignore"))`. Then you should be able to see the actual error.

Comment: Sorry @Kevin, I am beginner, how do I change this line, if its an error message, not the line created by me.

Comment: Edit the file `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py`

Comment: Changing the line is easy. Open the file `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py` in Notepad or some other editor, and replace the line that's there with the one I've suggested. Then save and run your script again.

Comment: Thank You @Kevin, I did what you said, and got another error.

Comment: playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 275 for command:
        open "Piano.wav" alias playsound_0.3574764503291783

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Answer (score 2):

The error you get (`275` = `MCIERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`) is that the system cannot find the sound file. You need to specify the complete path to the file, not only the file name:

```
playsound("C:\\Path\\To\\Piano.wav")
```

If the sound file is in the same directory or a subdirectory of where the script file is placed, see [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory) for how to get the path to the script file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when an non-UTF-8 character is in your path (like Ü, Ö...). Try to avoid having such characters in the path of your sound file.