# How to access files in subfolder independent of system?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I'd like to gather all .mp3 file paths in a folder (MP3) and assign them to keys in a dictionary, so my program works regardless of the system filepath (currently, filepaths are hardcoded, meaning the program only works on my own PC).

Here's the original setup:

```
NotePaths = {
"C" : "C:/.../MP3/C4.mp3",
"D" : "C:/.../MP3/D4.mp3",
"E" : "C:.../MP3/E4.mp3",
"F" : "C:/.../MP3/F4.mp3",
"G" : "C:/.../MP3/G4.mp3",
"A" : "C:/.../MP3/A4.mp3",
"H" : "C:/.../MP3/H4.mp3"
}
```

Here's what I tried to do to make the program work independent of the system folder structure, as long as there is a folder in the same folder where the program is located called MP3 (which includes the needed .mp3 files):

```
NotePaths = {
"C" : "",
"D" : "",
"E" : "",
"F" : "",
"G" : "",
"A" : "",
"H" : ""
}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/MP3"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("C"):
            NotePaths["C"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("D"):
            NotePaths["D"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("E"):
            NotePaths["E"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("F"):
            NotePaths["F"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("G"):
            NotePaths["G"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("A"):
            NotePaths["A"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))

        if file.endswith(".mp3") and file.startswith("H"):
            NotePaths["H"].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))
```

Attempting to run the program (which includes a playsound command to play the aforementioned .mp3 files) opens the playsound module and throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Musical Quiz.py", line 67, in <module>
    playsound(currentPath)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 60: invalid continuation byte
```

The filepaths are passed to the playsound function like this:

```
currentKey, currentPath = random.choice(list(NotePaths.items()))
playsound(currentPath)
```

**Update**:

I refactored my code according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66155204/14989165) (thanks!).
I have tried finding the actual problem as described here by modifying the playsound module (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979872/why-do-i-have-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc4-in-position-0-invalid-conti#comment104213251_58979872)) with the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Musical Quiz.py", line 67, in <module>
    playsound(currentPath)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 292 for command:
        open "" alias playsound_0.8907395801041198
    Der Befehl erfordert einen Alias-, Datei-, Treiber- oder Gertenamen.
    
##Attempted translation: the command requires an alias, file name, driver name or (I don't know what the last thing is)
```

So it seems like a) my code never worked from the beginning and failed to get the correct filepaths or b) playsound doesn't like what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this answer? [Why do I have "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte " problem and how do I solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979872/why-do-i-have-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc4-in-position-0-invalid-conti)

It gives an overview in how to troubleshoot such error, since it is kind of a high level error, and the actual error might be a file not found or a python versioning error.

#######

Also if I may do some refactoring of your code:

```
NotePaths = {
    "C" : "","D" : "","E" : "","F" : "","G" : "","A" : "","H" : ""
}

def file_startswith_key(file):
    """ Checking if file ends with wanted keys """
    for key in NotePaths:
        if file.startswith(key)
        return key, True
    return None, False

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/MP3"):
    for file in files:
        key, bool_value = file_startswith_key(file)
        if file.endswith(".mp3") and bool_value:
            NotePaths[key].append(Str("(os.path.join(root, file))"))
```

This would allow you to add as many keys as you want without adding new "if statements".

Comment: Thank you for linking to the question and refactoring my code :) I looked at the question you linked, but I'm still stuck.. I updated the original question and it'd be great if you could take a look!