# Django getting UnicodeDecodeError when using local chars

Tags: python, django, utf-8, pycharm

I have started a new project and app in Django 2.2.5 and I use Python 3.7.4 in Pycharm 2019.1.3

I run the django dev server from Pycharm terminal and everything works fine until I use some local signs in the html templates like: "í" after that I get UnicodeDecodeError:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 345: invalid continuation byte
```

In settings.py the Language code is set to local language:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'sk'
```

I am lost as to what to do with this. I tried trans and autoescape, setting the encoding at the top of the html file ... but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please, paste the character it is showing error at?

Comment: @HarshNagarkar: I did, it's in the text above: "í". I don't see why Django should have an issue with this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) suggests - this error most probably indicates that file (django template) contains invalid `utf-8` characters, more specifically - file most probably has `latin-1` encoding.

Some symbols may look the same in utf-8 / latin-1 but be encoded differently (a very common struggle when editing file on Windows, or inputting into web page that expects only utf-8).

Suggestion is to [configure PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-file-encodings.html) (and other editors you are using) to use `UTF-8` encoding and re-save file with it, possibly editing wrong characters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I already did that. This didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, let me correct myself .. yeah, you are right. Pycharm is kinda slow applying the settings ... but it's exactly this. Thanks.