# why does it give UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm doing a course of python on py4e, almost done, but chapter 11 seems like impossible because it gives me error every time.

**Error:**

```
line 4, in <module>
    lines = ffail.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

**Code:**

```
import re

ffail = open('regex_sum_340933.txt')
lines = ffail.read()
count = 0

match = re.findall('[0-9]+', lines)

for II in match:
    number = int(II)
    count = count + number
print(count)
```

Comment: can you post the data in the txt file

Comment: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_340933.txt

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it right. first of all you need to close the file I would suggest

to just use `with` so you won't need to worry about closing the file.

replace how you read the file with this

```
ffail = ""
with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", mode = "r" ,encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore',  buffering=-1) as some_file:
    ffail = some_file.read()
```

make sure that `regex_sum_340933.txt` is in the same directory as the file of the code.

if you are still having difficulties you could visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: Could you please accept the question/explain why it doesn't work and where is the problem?

Comment: Is the code supposed to look like this?
import re
ffail = ""
with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , "UTF-8") as some_file:
    ffail = some_file.read()
count = 0

match = re.findall('[0-9]+', ffail)

for II in match:
    number = int(II)
    count = count + number
print(count)
Gives this ERROR:  line 4, in <module>
    with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , "UTF-8") as some_file:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str).                                           I don't                understand what I need to do.

Comment: @RomeEsna Try and update your code with the err I can't understand

Comment: with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , "UTF-8") as some_file:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)                                                                                It gives me this error, any suggestions?

Comment: @RomeEsna See updated answer try with and without the `buffering` and show me the error if there is one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

lines = open('regex_sum_340933.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
count = sum(map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', lines)))
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping, the code wasn't wrong, just my Mac didn't want to make it work. Tried with windows and the answer came immediately.