# invalid continuation byte while using CSV file

Tags: python

When i tried opening a basic csv file with the below code I see the below error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 2587: invalid continuation byte
```

This is the code is wrote

```
import csv
f=open("/Users/local/Documents/practice.csv",'r')
c=csv.reader(f)
for row in c:
    print(row[1])
```

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) and this [library](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Balaji. I have installed the package.But still not able to figure out how to use it

Comment: Can you give me a link to download the file?

Comment: It worked now . I saved the file as csv.utf-8

Comment: Ok. Good to know.