# Issue with reading file encoding within python-Dash-base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, plotly-dash

I am using a dash program within python 3 where in I have a dcc.upload element, trying to upload files in dash. my code looks like below:

```
upload = html.Div([html.Label('Upload file'),
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-templ',
        children=html.Div(['Drag and Drop or ',html.A('Select Files')]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='data-upload')])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'xlsx' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf8')))
            ws = wb["sheet"]
            all_rows = list(ws.rows)
                        
            return html.Div([
            'its excell'
        ])
            
        elif 'temp' in filename:
            pptFilepath = io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf8'))
            return html.Div([
            'its powerpoint'
        ])
            
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            #df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

On uploading wither a PowerPoint or excel file i have it gives following error:

```
Powerpoint: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 15: invalid continuation byte
Excel: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

I know its related to my files that I am uploading. How can i solve this error?

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552555/9098350)

Comment: @bas van der No because this is a file and that was a string

Answer (score 0):

Use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`.

For example change this line

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf8')))
```

to this:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(io.BytesIO(decoded))
```

---

See the [`Upload` component example in the documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) for reference.