# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, object-detection

i am trying to retrain a model with tensorflow. I used the code from [Tensorflow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/) while following a Tutorial on Youtube. The process ends with the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Jeff\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 109, in as_text
> return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
> **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 9: invalid        continuation byte**

The Error happens to be in the following script compat.py in the highlighted line in the method "as_text":

```
def as_text(bytes_or_text, encoding='utf-8'):
  if isinstance(bytes_or_text, _six.text_type):
    return bytes_or_text
  elif isinstance(bytes_or_text, bytes):
    **return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)**
  else:
    raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' % bytes_or_text)
```

I googled for hours but couldn't find anything. I tried different pre-trained models and startet the installation and training configuration all over again. I am out of ideas and hope someone can help me here.

Can anybody tell me, what i can do to make it work? Thanks in advance!

Here the whole script compat.py :

````
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""Compatibility functions.

The `tf.compat` module contains two sets of compatibility functions.

## Tensorflow 1.x and 2.x APIs

The `compat.v1` and `compat.v2` submodules provide a complete copy of both the
`v1` and `v2` APIs for backwards and forwards compatibility across TensorFlow
versions 1.x and 2.x. See the
[migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for details.

## Utilities for writing compatible code

Aside from the `compat.v1` and `compat.v2` submodules, `tf.compat` also contains
a set of helper functions for writing code that works in both:

* TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x
* Python 2 and 3


## Type collections

The compatibility module also provides the following aliases for common
sets of python types:

* `bytes_or_text_types`
* `complex_types`
* `integral_types`
* `real_types`
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numbers as _numbers

import numpy as _np
import six as _six

from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export

try:
  # This import only works on python 3.3 and above.
  import collections.abc as collections_abc  # pylint: disable=unused-import
except ImportError:
  import collections as collections_abc  # pylint: disable=unused-import


def as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding='utf-8'):
  """Converts `bytearray`, `bytes`, or unicode python input types to `bytes`.

  Uses utf-8 encoding for text by default.

  Args:
    bytes_or_text: A `bytearray`, `bytes`, `str`, or `unicode` object.
    encoding: A string indicating the charset for encoding unicode.

  Returns:
    A `bytes` object.

  Raises:
    TypeError: If `bytes_or_text` is not a binary or unicode string.
  """
  if isinstance(bytes_or_text, bytearray):
    return bytes(bytes_or_text)
  elif isinstance(bytes_or_text, _six.text_type):
    return bytes_or_text.encode(encoding)
  elif isinstance(bytes_or_text, bytes):
    return bytes_or_text
  else:
    raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
                    (bytes_or_text,))


def as_text(bytes_or_text, encoding='utf-8'):
  """Converts any string-like python input types to unicode.

  Returns the input as a unicode string. Uses utf-8 encoding for text
  by default.

  Args:
    bytes_or_text: A `bytes`, `str`, or `unicode` object.
    encoding: A string indicating the charset for decoding unicode.

  Returns:
    A `unicode` (Python 2) or `str` (Python 3) object.

  Raises:
    TypeError: If `bytes_or_text` is not a binary or unicode string.
  """
  if isinstance(bytes_or_text, _six.text_type):
    return bytes_or_text
  elif isinstance(bytes_or_text, bytes):
    return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
  else:
    raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' % bytes_or_text)


def as_str(bytes_or_text, encoding='utf-8'):
  if _six.PY2:
    return as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
  else:
    return as_text(bytes_or_text, encoding)

tf_export('compat.as_text')(as_text)
tf_export('compat.as_bytes')(as_bytes)
tf_export('compat.as_str')(as_str)


@tf_export('compat.as_str_any')
def as_str_any(value):
  """Converts input to `str` type.

     Uses `str(value)`, except for `bytes` typed inputs, which are converted
     using `as_str`.

  Args:
    value: A object that can be converted to `str`.

  Returns:
    A `str` object.
  """
  if isinstance(value, bytes):
    return as_str(value)
  else:
    return str(value)


@tf_export('compat.path_to_str')
def path_to_str(path):
  r"""Converts input which is a `PathLike` object to `str` type.

  Converts from any python constant representation of a `PathLike` object to
  a string. If the input is not a `PathLike` object, simply returns the input.

  Args:
    path: An object that can be converted to path representation.

  Returns:
    A `str` object.

  Usage:
    In case a simplified `str` version of the path is needed from an
    `os.PathLike` object

  Examples:
  ```python
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str('C:\XYZ\tensorflow\./.././tensorflow')
  'C:\XYZ\tensorflow\./.././tensorflow' # Windows OS
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str(Path('C:\XYZ\tensorflow\./.././tensorflow'))
  'C:\XYZ\tensorflow\..\tensorflow' # Windows OS
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str(Path('./corpus'))
  'corpus' # Linux OS
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str('./.././Corpus')
  './.././Corpus' # Linux OS
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str(Path('./.././Corpus'))
  '../Corpus' # Linux OS
  $ tf.compat.path_to_str(Path('./..////../'))
  '../..' # Linux OS

  ```
  """
  if hasattr(path, '__fspath__'):
    path = as_str_any(path.__fspath__())
  return path


def path_to_bytes(path):
  r"""Converts input which is a `PathLike` object to `bytes`.

  Converts from any python constant representation of a `PathLike` object
  or `str` to bytes.

  Args:
    path: An object that can be converted to path representation.

  Returns:
    A `bytes` object.

  Usage:
    In case a simplified `bytes` version of the path is needed from an
    `os.PathLike` object
  """
  if hasattr(path, '__fspath__'):
    path = path.__fspath__()
  return as_bytes(path)


# Numpy 1.8 scalars don't inherit from numbers.Integral in Python 3, so we
# need to check them specifically.  The same goes from Real and Complex.
integral_types = (_numbers.Integral, _np.integer)
tf_export('compat.integral_types').export_constant(__name__, 'integral_types')
real_types = (_numbers.Real, _np.integer, _np.floating)
tf_export('compat.real_types').export_constant(__name__, 'real_types')
complex_types = (_numbers.Complex, _np.number)
tf_export('compat.complex_types').export_constant(__name__, 'complex_types')

# Either bytes or text.
bytes_or_text_types = (bytes, _six.text_type)
tf_export('compat.bytes_or_text_types').export_constant(__name__,
                                                        'bytes_or_text_types')
````

Comment: Question: is your input actually valid utf-8, or is it in some other encoding?

Comment: Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte