# Why do I face such error when I import data throught pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

As a beginner, I am trying to import data with the name of (Facebook_Ads_2.csv) using pandas on jupyter notebook; the output must be as shown below.

[image]

but when I import them using the following lines of Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = pd.read_csv('Facebook_Ads_2.csv')
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 T = pd.read_csv('Facebook_Ads_2.csv')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:912, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
    899 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    900     dialect,
    901     delimiter,
   (...)
    908     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    909 )
    910 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 912 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:577, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    574 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    576 # Create the parser.
--> 577 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    579 if chunksize or iterator:
    580     return parser

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1407, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1404     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1406 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1407 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1679, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1676     raise ValueError(msg)
   1678 try:
-> 1679     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1680 except Exception:
   1681     if self.handles is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:93, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     90 if kwds["dtype_backend"] == "pyarrow":
     91     # Fail here loudly instead of in cython after reading
     92     import_optional_dependency("pyarrow")
---> 93 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     95 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
     97 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:548, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:637, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:848, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:2017, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 4001: invalid continuation byte
```

**Any assistance, please?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: pandas assumes your file uses UTF-8 encoding.  Your file is not UTF-8.  You can override the encoding in the `read_csv` call.

Comment: How, exactly, was the `Facebook_Ads_2.csv` file created?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am following a course; this file is by the course, and he did not solve it for us. I am trying to solve it by myself.

Comment: @kabanus Thank you sir, but I did not understand the problem.

Comment: Since this is on Windows, you might try `pd.read_csv('Facebook_Ads_2.csv', encoding='cp1252')`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this can happen because of unexpected symbols in one of the rows.

From the pandas version **1.3.0**, there's a handler for these types of errors.

You can try calling  `encoding_errors` parameter in `read_csv()`:

```py
T = pd.read_csv('Facebook_Ads_2.csv', encoding_errors='ignore')
```

See what does it return, or you can try another [type of handling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) encoding errors

If your pandas version is older than 1.3.0, let me know and we can try to come up with different solution to your problem